# iPhone unexpected duplication of TCP packets on different ports

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, nsurlconnection, boost-asio

I'm running this simple asio-based [program](http://pastebin.com/wRjxt1Qn):

```
Address address = Address::from_string(host);
Tcp::endpoint ep(address, port);
Tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(ep);
Tcp::socket socket(io_service);
asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);
```

Everything works fine on my host machine, but when this program run under iOS (both iphone and iphonesimulator) my sniffer detect some unexpected packets:

```
# client: 192.168.1.10, server: 192.168.1.100
# everything fine...
5.359761000 192.168.1.10  192.168.1.100  52712 [SYN]
5.359989000 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.10   52712 [SYN, ACK]
5.364103000 192.168.1.10  192.168.1.100  52712 [ACK]
5.364103000 192.168.1.10  192.168.1.100  52712 [FIN, ACK]
5.364386000 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.10   52712 [FIN, ACK]
5.366095000 192.168.1.10  192.168.1.100  52712 [ACK]
# Here comes unexpected part...
5.632569000 192.168.1.10  192.168.1.100  52716 [SYN]
5.632891000 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.10   52716 [SYN, ACK]
5.638314000 192.168.1.10  192.168.1.100  52716 [ACK]
5.638633000 192.168.1.10  192.168.1.100  52716 [FIN, ACK]
5.639017000 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.10   52716 [FIN, ACK]
5.644743000 192.168.1.10  192.168.1.100  52716 [ACK]
```

The strangest part is that unexpected packets received **after** main (successfully) exit. I've detect this packets on both client (when use simulator) and server side.

Where did they comes from? How can I fix it?

#### Update

Same behaviour with raw [BSD-sockets](http://pastebin.com/M4AR2HwW) and [NSURLConnection](http://pastebin.com/F1eCHcgs). There is no such packets if I use Safari or Chrome to access server.

#### Update 2

- "normal" packets dump: [status line only](http://pastebin.com/H4UfxMKT), [expanded](http://pastebin.com/0fkJXciC)
- dump with unexpected packets: [status line only](http://pastebin.com/YQeWXcXY), [expanded](http://pastebin.com/ftSH3pMb)

#### Update 3

- version with `getpid`: http://pastebin.com/w1niwMMU

Comment: Does your server accept packets on this port?

Comment: @JefferyThomas yep, I can read expected content (it's http server)

Comment: What problem is this causing you? And what is the fourth column in your data? Could this be caused by some other process running in the app, like, say, reachability detection?

Comment: @JesseRusak "And what is the fourth column in your data?" TCP port

Comment: @JesseRusak "Could this be caused by some other process running in the app, like, say, reachability detection?" This packets are definitely somehow related to my application.

Comment: @JesseRusak "What problem is this causing you?" Well, it's not some major problem) I'm just suspicious about unexpected traffic.

Comment: Is there any data in that second stream? What server-side port is it connected to?

Comment: @JesseRusak "Is there any data in that second stream?" There is no data neither in first stream nor in second. It's simple tcp connection establishing process without any data.

Comment: @JesseRusak "What server-side port is it connected to?" 8080. Take a look at the sources.

Comment: My questions were not about the expected behavior; I'm asking whether your sniffer shows any data in those streams and what port it shows them connected to.

Comment: @JesseRusak "what port it shows them connected to" I've already answered this question, please read above.

Comment: @JesseRusak "whether your sniffer shows any data" I'm already answered this question, too, there is no data in packets. It's TCP packets with zero length.

Comment: ruslo, I have read your code and comments; I see that your code is connecting to server-side port 8080 and sends and expects no data. I am asking if, when you inspect the packets themselves with your sniffer whether they, in fact, match your expectations about the server-side port and contents. If they do not, that might give a clue as to what they are. A full binary dump of those packets might also help someone answer your question.

Comment: @JesseRusak I've add a dump of packets in both situations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is a bug or a feature, but what's happening is that when your app exits with a return value of 0, it gets re-started by launchd. So, your app is running twice and therefore tries its TCP connection twice.

You can verify this by adding, say `sleep(10)` just before you return from your main function; if you watch a process monitor, you'll see it launch, run for 10 seconds and then quit, get re-launched and run for another 10 seconds.

If you return a non-zero exit code or simply don't exit (as iOS apps usually don't), this won't happen.

Comment: Thanks! You're absolutely right, it's so simple)) I've add one more example with sending `pid` and sniffer detect different `pid`s)) And first example not printing "OK" message twice because Xcode thinks that my dup app is just another process and is not the process he need to debug and show debug output)))